# Unir celdas verticalemente que contienen arrays

Tags: php, html, array

soy nuevo en php y estoy teniendo problemas para unir celdas de manera vertical que contienen arrays respectivamente, el caso es que contienen el mismo contenido, lo que quiero es juntar todo y omitir valores repetidos, no se si me di a entender. Les anexo mi código que recibe un string por medio de un textarea,por lo general es un archivo .csv el que recibe(es el mismo codigo solo que lo tuve que poner en 2 partes por que no me detectaba con el php dentro stackoverflow [image: codigo php]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Box Lunch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
           <!--Este es mi boton de regreso-->
           <form name="buttonbar">
               <div class="container" align="center">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="CONVERTIR OTRO" onClick="history.back()">
               </div>
               <br>
            </form>
            <br>
            <!--Aqui inicializo lq tabla-->
            <table border="1" width="90%" align="center">
            <thead>
                <th>Día</th>
                <th>Clave</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Hora</th>
                <th>BoxLunch</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $box = (count($value['horas']) > 3) ? 1 : "";
                    echo '<tr colspan="2">
                        <td align="center">'.$value['dia'].'</td>
                        <td align="center">'.$value['clave'].'</td>
                        <td align="center">'.$value['nombre'].'</td>
                        <td align="center">'.implode("<br/>", $value['horas']).'</td>
                        <td align="center">'.$box.'</td>
                    </tr>';
                 }

                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Aqui esta el ejemplo, donde señala que solo sea un valor por, persona y que omita los nombre repetidos
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entendí, todos los valores se mantienen igual, excepto horas, que puede tener 1 o más elementos. Conviene crear cada elemento de `$data` con los datos que no cambian y después agregar las horas.

**Edición:** Solo el nombre se mantiene, el resto de valores se coloca como array.

```
<?php

$aDatos = explode("\n", $_POST['areatexto']);
$data = [];

foreach($aDatos as $value) {
    $valores = explode(',', $value);
    // Para facilitar el manejo de índice en $data
    // El índice debe ser el nombre
    $index = $valores[2];
    if(!isset($data[$index])) {
        // Si no existe el elemento, hay que inicializarlo
        $data[$index] = [
            // dia, clave y nombre siempre van a ser los mismos
            'dia' => [],
            'clave' => [],
            'nombre' => $valores[2],
            'horas' => []
        ];
    }
    // Se agregan días, claves y horas array correspondiente
    $data[$index]['dia'][] = $valores[0];
    $data[$index]['clave'][] = $valores[1];
    $data[$index]['horas'][] = $valores[3];
}


    // Para generar la tabla
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $box = (count($value['horas']) > 3) ? 1 : "";
        echo '<tr colspan="2">
            <td align="center">' . implode("<br/>", $value['dia']) . '</td>
            <td align="center">' . implode("<br/>", $value['clave'] . '</td>
            <td align="center">' . $value['nombre'].'</td>
            <td align="center">' . implode("<br/>", $value['horas']) . '</td>
            <td align="center">' . $box . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
```

Comment: si bro, esta mas organizado asi ,como te digo soy nuevo, de hecho es mi primer lenguaje de programacion real que estoy aprendiendo, pero como podria hacer para que el area de nombres de la tabla, solo aparezca un nombre, y se omitan los repetidos?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, agrega una muestra de datos y cómo quieres que se vean.

Comment: si, te dejo la imagen

Comment: listo, ya lo deje

Comment: Ya está modificada. Por cierto, cuando necesites agregar información, **no agregues una respuesta**, edita tu pregunta.

Comment: no carga imagenes bro, y no supe como hacerle, perdon, pero gracias bro, me haz ayudado un monton, estoy agradecido con tu apoyo! :D